# Out of bound array elements being printed using gcc in Win8

Tags: c, gcc

I'm compiling the following code in my m/c using codeblocks and mingw32-gcc.exe v.4.8.1(tdm-2).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a[8] = {3,1,10,-1,7,2,-8,1};
    int b[8] = {3,1,10,-1,7,2,-8,1};
    int i=0,alength = (int)sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);

    for(i = 0; i < alength; i++){
            if(a[i] > a[i+1]){
                a[i+1] = a[i] + a[i+1];
                a[i] = a[i+1] - a[i];
                a[i+1] = a[i+1] - a[i];
            }
    }

    printf("Original array size is %d \n", alength);
    printf("Original array elements are given below: \n");
    printf("Sizeof(a) is %d \n", sizeof(a));
    for(i = 0; i < alength; i++){
        printf("\n b[%d] = %d", i, b[i]);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < alength; i++){
        printf("\na[%d] = %d", i, a[i]);
    }
}
```

It's giving me the following output. Here for each array, two extra elements are being printed.

```
Original array size is 10 
Original array elements are given below: 
Sizeof(a) is 32 

 b[0] = 3
 b[1] = 1
 b[2] = 10
 b[3] = -1
 b[4] = 7
 b[5] = 2
 b[6] = -8
 b[7] = 1
 b[8] = 1
 b[9] = 3
a[0] = 1
a[1] = 3
a[2] = -1
a[3] = 7
a[4] = 2
a[5] = -8
a[6] = 1
a[7] = 8
a[8] = 10
a[9] = 9
```

But compiling the same code in [online compiler](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php) gives the correct output. OS is Win8 64bit. Any help in explaining and resolving the difference would be appreciated..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accessing out of bound array element invokes undefined behavior and this will result in any expected or unexpected result.

Change

```
 for(i = 0; i < alength; i++){
        if(a[i] > a[i+1]){ ...
        ...
  }
```

to

```
 for(i = 0; i < alength-1; i++){
        if(a[i] > a[i+1]){ ...
        ...
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting the mistake in accessing array out of bound.

Answer (score 4):

What you have is the very definition of undefined behaviour, specifically the one pass bubble sort you're trying to write. `i` goes from `0` to `alength-1`, covering the entire array, then you index `a[i+1]`, which is going to be past the end.

If I had to guess specifically what's causing the difference, one machine is building in debug mode introducing a sentinel between `a` and `b`, so in one instance you're comparing `a[7]` with either `b[0]` (going to swap) or with `a[8]` (the sentinel, which is usually a large number so not going to swap).

TL;DR: Undefined behaviour.

Comment: One might add that the calculation of array size is wrong. And the unknown undefined behaviour becomes predictable.

Comment: It's never predictable unless you lock down every single thing involved in getting that code running, and even then you'll only know once you run it which path it takes.

Comment: @icbytes Calculation of `alength` is correct, but it's probably overwritten when writing past the end of array.

Comment: Sorry I'm not able to understand. The value of `alength` is going to 10 instead of 8, which is the dealbreaker. Mind explaining why this behavior?

Comment: @kaydee Print `alength` before first `for` loop, and you'll see it's correct.

Comment: How is it correct,when it prints 10 instead of 8 ? I assume no lf cr.

Comment: @kaydee when `i == 7` in your loop, then `a[i+1]` (i.e., `a[8]`) is outside the array as the last array element is `a[7]`. You are overwriting an object outside the array which happens to be your `alength` object.

Comment: @blindy another likely difference is that the build that "works" is optimizing "alength" away having determined that it's only assigned once with a compile-time constant value, meaning that it's the saved parent stack frame pointer that gets corrupted. As the code is in main (), that value won't get used again.